# Keras with tensorflow error when prediction

Tags: django, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I working with sjango and I am trying to predict a image  using Keras with tensorflow backend but I have this error :

```
line 3669, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_6/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 50), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
[28/Apr/2019 16:54:53] "POST /facture/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 133945
```

Here is my code :

```
#Loading the model 
pwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(pwd+'/ModelML/model_architecture19.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())
# Load weights into the new model
model.load_weights(pwd+'/ModelML/model_weights19.h5')



roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret2, roi = cv2.threshold(roi, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)    
            roi = cv2.resize(roi, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) # Resize the image
            roi = roi.reshape(1,IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE,1)
            #normalize image
            roi = roi /255 


            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            with graph.as_default():
                pred =model.predict(roi)
```

The error come from the last line "model predict"

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I would recommend to check whether weights is tally with the architecture or not.

Comment: Yes it is the same

Answer (score 0):

Is `graph = tf.get_default_graph()` inside a function or a method?

What about move it to right after `model.load_weights(pwd+'/ModelML/model_weights19.h5')`
?

These line

```
pwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(pwd+'/ModelML/model_architecture19.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())
# Load weights into the new model
model.load_weights(pwd+'/ModelML/model_weights19.h5')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

should be outside of any class or function.

Comment: thanks I have the same error :     raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 50), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
[28/Apr/2019 21:43:42] "POST /facture/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132809

Comment: graph = tf.get_default_graph() is out  of function

Comment: I have something différent before the error was ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_6/Softmax:0".. now I have  ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 50)

Comment: It has changed densr_4 to dense_6